# Upgrading to Haml 5.0 removes dynamic quote support leading to parsing error by Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, haml

Created this issue in the Haml github: https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/1023

Upgrading to Haml 5.0 is causing changes due to removal of dynamic quotes functionality

For example, if I were to use Nokogiri to parse the following haml (where "..." is another partial)

```
%a.nav{:"data-content" => render ... }
```

I get

```
<a class='nav' data-content='<div id='...'>' >
```

When what I wanted was

```
<a class='nav' data-content="<div id='...'>" >
```

Running

```
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("<a class='nav' data-content='<div id='...'>'>")
```

Gives me

```
#(Attr:0x3f7ea6e9adcc { name = "data-content", value = "<div id=" })
```

Running

```
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("<a class='nav' data-content=\"<div id='...'>\">")
```

Gives me back

```
#(Attr:0x3f7ea6c0b4e4 { name = "data-content", value = "<div id='...'>" })
```

It seems that removal of dynamic quote functionality has affected the ability to parse through the HTML output. Is there a way to re-enable dynamic quoting, or to fix the issue some other way?

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri problem. And, it appears you might have found a bug, but that really doesn't make it on-topic for SO. Can you explain why it is on-topic? Consistent use of single and double-quotes is always an issue when dealing with parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an already existing issue here: https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/925, which solved my problem.

The solution seems to be to do

```
%a.nav{:"data-content" => "#{render ... }" }
```